# ORA-12705 error when trying to connect SQL developer with Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect **SQL Developer** with **Oracle Database**, but in the end again one error is showing again and again after clicking on "Test".

I tried it again after changing the Port to "*1522*" from "*1521*" but the same thing is happening, I am using **Windows 10**.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsGhl.jpg)

I have attached the screenshot as above.

Comment: For ORA-12705 errors caused by invalid NLS_LANG settings, you need to verify that it is "unset" at the system-level:

Windows - The NLS_LANG must be unset in the Windows registry (re-named is best).  Look for the NLS_LANG subkey in the registry at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE, and rename it.
 
Linux/UNIX - Here you simply issue the Linux command "unset NLS_LANG"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add following lines to %SQL_DEV_HOME%\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.country=US
```

Apart from this you can check few things:

Verify oracle xe database settings by executing this in sqlplus:
`select userenv('LANGUAGE') from dual;`
Result of this query can be ENGLISH_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252)

Change regional settings in control panel according to your database (For this example it can be changed to English (United States))

Change NLS parameters in sql developer according to your database and regional settings